# Eigenvalues of product of a positive definite matrix with a Hurwitz matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$W$ is a positive definite matrix.

$C=\pmatrix{-H &  -A^T\\\
     A  &  0}$,
where $H>0$ and $A$ is full rank. (It can be shown that all eigenvalues of $C$ have negative real part.) We know that (it can be shown) that all the eigenvalues of $WC$ have negative real part. What is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $WC$ and $C$? Can we show that $W>I$ results in the real part of the eigenvalues of $CW$ being more negative that $C$'s?